# System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, windows, file

I trying to copy a file from a temporary directory to a folder which a user chooses. I am using C#, and the folder that I'm using is empty.

The code i'm using is:

```
File.Copy(srcPath, landscapebox.Text, true);
```

`srcPath` is a temporary folder

`landscapebox` is a text box which will have a directory inputted into it. It should look like:

```
"C:\Users\####\Folder\Folder"
```

But instead I get:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The target file "C:\Users\###\Desktop\####\TestFolder" is a directory, not a file.
```

Help! I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the second argument in [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx) is the destination *file path* not the destination *folder path*.

You can construct the destination file name from your input folder like this:

```
File.Copy(srcPath, 
    Path.Combine(landscapebox.Text, Path.GetFileName(srcPath)), true);
```

Comment: Oh. That's embarrasing